# Blazor: Razor component @bind-

Tags: razor, blazor

.NET 5 / Blazor / VS 2019

How do you handle @bind- which do nothing?

Example:

```
<Switch TValue="bool" @bind-Check="@IsFoo"></Switch>
```

or

<Switch TValue="bool" @bind-xxddfgdg="@IsFoo">

IsFoo is always False

No compiler error or warning, runtime result IsFoo = **False**

With Blazor **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For two-way binding to work you have to use `EventCallback<>`. The name of the callback should match your binding parameter with `Changed` appended to it.

In this example I use `Value` and `ValueChanged`.

`Switch.razor`

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input @bind="@Value"
           type="checkbox"
           class="custom-control-input"
           id="customSwitch1"/>
    <label class="custom-control-label"
           for="customSwitch1">
        @Label
    </label>
</div>

@code {
    bool switchValue = false;

    [Parameter]
    public bool Value
    {
        get => switchValue;
        set
        {
            if (switchValue == value) return;
            switchValue = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Switch @bind-Value="@myValue" Label="Toggle this switch element"/>
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GlYqkRvm32i7ZAiN53)

Comment: This is what I'm doing - Checked instead of Value.  
Checked it with https://blazorfiddle.com/ and yes that works only with bind-Checked as expected. Only in my VS 2019 solution i could do bind-Whatever without any errors. 
Have to look deeper in the project. Strange. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @DominikOswald Yes seems odd. However it does not run. You will get a runtime error.